# RoundUp - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to try and roundup **in Angular**, which on the whole works, however numbers less than 0.5 are rounded to 0. I would like to **round up** every number to the next whole number. E.g 0.02 should be rounded to 1

`{{((data.Virtual.SumCores/data.Physical.SumCores) | number:0)*1}}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this

```
Math.ceil(4.4); //Returns 5
Math.ceil(0.002); //Returns 1
```

The filter

```
 .filter('roundup', function () {
        return function (value) {
            return Math.ceil(value);
        };
    })
```

The HTML

```
{{ yourdata | roundup }}
```

reference

[JS Math](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp)

Comment: This isn't really an angularjs solution

Answer (score 2):

You can create a filter for this:

```
.filter('roundup', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Math.ceil(input);
  };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{ data.Virtual.SumCores/data.Physical.SumCores | roundup }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all of the answers are based on Math.ceil() function, you can simply add

```
$scope.Math=window.Math;
```

into your controller and use it like this:

```
{{ Math.ceil(data.Virtual.SumCores/data.Physical.SumCores) }}
```

This way you get the access to all Math functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you add 0.999 first, it should round up instead of down.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: if you make the expression like this, the rounding should be correct: {{((0.999 + data.Virtual.SumCores/data.Physical.SumCores) | number:0)*1}}

Comment: sorry, it should be 0.5 instead of 0.999

Comment: **+ 0.49** actually, otherwise 0 will be 0,5, which will be 1. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you should create a new filter to do that:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('ceil', function(){
  return function(input) {
    return Math.ceil(+input);
  };
})
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.numbers = [0.2,1.5,1.3,5.5,3,10,0.5];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="n in numbers">
    {{n | ceil}}
  </div>

</div>
```