# how to remove decimal part from the data in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While im removing the decimal , its getting round off . but i want to remove decimal point only. while my data is 3.7 , im getting 4.

```
sample data 3.7
Exp op 3
```

code

```
 <li class="temp">Temperature  <span> {{Temperature.Ch1Temp | number:0}} </span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `Math.floor()`?

```
<li class="temp">Temperature  <span>{{ Math.floor(Temperature.Ch1Temp) }}</span></li>
```

Just keep in mind how that will also impact negative numbers.

### Angular JS

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments, you will need to bind the `Math` library into your controller, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278872/1024832), and excerpted as follows:

```
$scope.Math = window.Math;
```

AngularJS Example [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/A97d9AWlQh5HaiSi).

### Modern Angular

If you're using a modern Angular, you'll need to explicitly assign the `Math` library in your component's Typescript, like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  number = 3.7;
  Math = Math; //explicitly bind the Math library so it's usable in template
}
```

There's a working Stackblitz example [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-samtbs?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

Comment: Makes the number filter redundant and could remove it.  `{{Math.floor(Temperature.Ch1Temp)}}`

Comment: Good point, @charlietfl.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: while im using Math.floor inside angular bracket its giving me error. error - Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you used correct capitalization and syntax?  You need to be more specific about what your error is if you expect anyone to be able to help you. `Math.floor()` is standard javascript, which Angular can access in this way.

Comment: i used Math.floor properly inside the angular brackets. but its not working. without Math.floor im getting value.

Comment: @Marc kindly check this .https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJLXK852JSVZ here also Math.floor not working.

Comment: @Vinod you need to bind `Math.floor(Temperature.Ch1Temp)` to some variable within the controller and then pass it as a value. Or you have to bind the Math object to scope, `$scope.Math = window.Math;`, in order to use it

Comment: @Marc the question is tagged with angularjs.

Comment: Ugh, you're right, @Phobos. My mistake.  I enhanced my answer further for both AngularJS and Angular. Not sure what I was thinking, but thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the number into an int using `parseInt` inside a js function