# Angular - remove the decimal

Tags: angular

I am beginner in Angular, I have to replace the number `12 568,000` in `12 568`on the screen.

Into the HTML file, I search the value, but I only have this information:

```
<tr style="background-color: #f8f9fa;">
    ...
    <td style="width: 10%;">{{'3452' | t}}</td>
</tr>
```

I know that the line is below:

```
<td style="width: 10%;">{{'3452' | t}}</td>
```

But, how can I format this in fact?

On this page
[how to remove decimal part from the data in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306637/how-to-remove-decimal-part-from-the-data-in-angular-js)

I have to use `{{myvariable:0}}`

I tried

```
 <td style="width: 10%;">{{'3452' | t:0 }}</td>
```

But, nothing has been changed.

Do have you an idea please?

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Comment: your variable is a number or is a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pipe or `Math` function to remove decimal part of number.

To use `Math` in your template you need to define variable (say `math`) and assign to `Math` in you component.

Like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  math = Math;
}
```

And in your template use `trunc` function to remove decimal part:

```
<div>
  {{math.trunc(3452.200)}} //output is 3452
</div>
```

Another way is using decimal pipe.
Like this:

```
<div style="width: 10%;">{{'3452.20022' | number: '1.0-0'}}</div>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr89dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is working sample I prepare for you.

Comment: Be very very careful of what you want to achieve!
I had the same issue, and I found this Answer, great for the first time, and I used the second method, with the Pipe... BUT if your number is over .5, it will be rounded UP... this made a big difference for me. So keep this in mind. 

But very good answer.